# How to use classes that extends Activity in Android?

Tags: java, android, class, android-activity, extends

I am new to Android programming.

Basically what I want to do is write a class that extends `Activity` and then use it in another class that also extends `Activity`.

In my case what I wanted to do was to be able use `GsmCellLocation` class members without having to initialise `TelephonyManager`.

So I created a class named as `CellInformation` and here is the content:

```
public class CellInformation extends Activity {

    private TelephonyManager tm;
    private GsmCellLocation cellLoc;

    public CellInformation() { 
        tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        cellLoc = (GsmCellLocation) tm.getCellLocation();
    }

    public GsmCellLocation updateCellInfo() {
        cellLoc = (GsmCellLocation) tm.getCellLocation();
        return cellLoc;
    }

    public int getCid() {
        return (cellLoc.getCid()%65536);
    }

    public int getLac() {
        return cellLoc.getLac();
    }

    public int getPsc() {
        return cellLoc.getPsc();
    }

}
```

and within my main activity this is how I initialise it:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    cell = new CellInformation();
}
```

I am getting `System services not available to Activities before onCreate()` error. If I was not meant to initialise it within onCreate, then where should I initialise it?
If my logic is completely wrong and/or this is not Android standard, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Simply Don't extend the Activity until it is required. I saw the class `CellInformation` where Activity class not required. Remove it and it will solve your problem.

```
public class CellInformation  {
  ..... // Method and Attributes.
   private Context context;

   CellInformation(Context context) {
     this.context = context;
     tm = (TelephonyManager)this.context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
   }
}
```

In Activity make the object of this class like :-

```
cell = new CellInformation(this);
```

Now, Make the object of this class in the activity where your require then call the method of this `CellInformation`.

Comment: In that case `getSystemService` method does not work. That is the reason why I extend Activity...

Comment: I updated the answer and check it now. When you make the object of this class, pass the context of activity into the constructor of the `CellInformation` class and Use this context to call the  `context.getSystemService`

Comment: Thanks, but my question was about using classes that extends Activity, your answer is telling me not to extend Activity which is an alternative approach to solve a very specific problem.

Comment: There is no use of extend the Activity class in `CellInformation`. You should not extend it